# Check hosts file for entity using batch script in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, hosts

I have hosts file with entity in it **address:hosts** and want to check if given entity presents in the hosts file. So I wrote:
In hosts file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
129.0.2.2 tralala.com
```

And in my batch script i wrote:

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off

@rem ############################################
@rem # Remove host from windows hosts file      #
@rem ############################################

if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

:start
set "hostpath=%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
goto addFindIPAddress

:addFindIPAddress
@rem set the string you wish to find
set find="129.0.2.2 tralala.com"
goto checkHosts

:checkHosts
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%hostpath%) do call :processline %%a
goto :mainEnd

:processline
set line=%*
if NOT line == find (
echo %line%
)
goto :eof

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal
PAUSE
```

So I want to print all lines that are different from find line but nothing happens so I am wondering were is my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The batch comparison operator `==` is space sensitive and the variables must be expanded for comparison.**  The spaces around the `==` operator must be removed and the variables must be expanded or just the variable names will be compared.

```
if not "%line%"=="%find%" (
```

That is the primary issue with your script.  However, I would recommend using the `find` command to perform this task.

```
find /v "129.0.2.2 tralala.com" "%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Comment: Also do not work if I set `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then 
`if not !line!==!find! (` then everything is ok.